# split a large file to new file with unique file names

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep, split

I need to split a file into unique file names.
I can do it with `sed` command eg,  `sed -n '/scaffold135_/w 135-scaf.txt' input file.txt` but it's time consuming so I need a smart way to do it faster. Below is an input sample (the original file has one million lines):

```
scaffold1_115,T,N,N,N,N,A,N,N,N,N,N,N,T,N,T,T,N,A,A,N,N,A
scaffold1_123,A,N,N,N,N,G,N,N,N,N,N,N,A,N,A,A,N,G,G,N,N,G
scaffold1_140,C,N,N,N,N,C,N,N,N,N,N,N,C,N,C,C,N,T,C,N,N,C
scaffold2_161,G,N,N,N,N,G,N,C,N,N,C,N,G,N,G,G,N,G,G,C,N,G
scaffold2_162,C,N,N,N,N,C,N,T,N,N,T,N,C,N,C,C,N,C,C,T,N,C
scaffold2_180,C,N,N,N,N,C,N,T,N,N,C,C,C,T,C,C,T,C,C,C,N,C
scaffold2_194,C,N,N,C,N,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,T,C,C,C,C,C,N,C
scaffold3_195,G,N,N,G,G,C,G,G,G,G,G,G,C,G,C,G,G,C,C,G,N,C
scaffold3_234,T,N,A,T,A,A,T,T,T,A,T,A,A,T,A,A,T,A,A,T,N,A
scaffold101_282,C,T,T,T,C,C,T,C,T,C,C,C,C,T,C,C,T,C,C,C,N,C
scaffold101_371,T,T,T,T,T,C,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,N,C
scaffold101_372,T,T,T,T,C,C,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,N,C
```

The lines are unique. I want lines specific to each `scafold` into a separate file, say all lines that start with `scaffold1_` into a file named `scaffold1.txt` and so on until `scaffold10156.txt` which contains the lines starting with `scaffold10156_`

Comment: welcomme to U&L, can you edit your post with what you have tried so far ?

Comment: How many lines do you want in each file? Or is there a pattern (change) that identifies where the splits should be applied?

Comment: Hi roaima, thank you for your reply, the lines are unique. i want that unique line into one file, say all lines that start with scaffold1_ to a new file, and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) with `awk`

```
awk -F'_' '{print > $1".txt"}' file
```

If lines sharing the `scaffoldn_` prefix are contiguous, you could do the following to avoid breaching open file handles limit

```
awk -F'_' 'NR == 1 || $1 != prev{if (f) close(f);f=$1".txt"; prev=$1}; 
{print > f};END{if (f) close(f)}' file
```

Comment: Hai, 1_CR, thank you for your comment, i am a learner, i tried your command, it throws out an error,awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {print > >>>  $1".txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: The code works perfectly for me. Do you have the quote chars correct, @kapr0001? What shell are you using? What operating system? Which `awk` version (`awk -V`)?

Comment: @kapr0001, are you sure you copied the command over properly, including the double-quotes and enclosing single quotes

Comment: yes, copied all the chars, and i am using unix shell (terminal).

Comment: @don_crissti, shell GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)  and awk version 20070501

Comment: @don_crissti, yes it works upto 16 output files, then i get an error, awk: scaffold17.txt makes too many open files
 input record number 159003, file input
 source line number 1

Comment: @kapr0001 You have to remove all `scanfold` files before script start and use `>>` instead of `>` in `print` command and add `close($1".txt")` as second command

Comment: @kapr0001, assuming all lines for each `scaffold` prefix are contiguous, can you try `awk -F'_' 'NR == 1 || $1 != prev{if (f) close(f);f=$1".txt"; prev=$1}; {print > f}' file`?

Comment: @1_CR perfect, thank you very much. saved my time..!

Answer (score 1):

For **GNU sed**:

```
sed 's/scaffold\([0-9]*\)_.*/echo "&" >> "\1-scaf.txt"/e' infile
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, i have tried your command, with an error sed: illegal option -- r

Comment: @kapr0001 See edited